# How to sum two indices of time series?

Tags: time-series, descriptive-statistics

I have two time series $X_{t,A}$ and $X_{t,B}$ with an index (2015=100) as unit of measure. To be more concrete, my two time series are the index of the level of employment in countries A and B. I want to sum both of them. Of course, it does not make sense to do $X_{t,A}+X_{t,B}$.

I do not have the time series of the level of employment for each country, but I do have the level of employment for one specific period (starting just before the beginning of the time series). I will call them $L_A$ and $L_B$.

Can I compute the relative share of employment in each country to sum the two indices? Formally :

$X_{t} = w_AX_{t,A} + w_BX_{t,B}$

with

$w_A = \frac{L_A}{L_A+L_B}$ and $w_B = \frac{L_B}{L_A+L_B}$

I understand that this is an approximation, but does it make sense to you? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: By "level", do you mean the total *absolute* number of employed persons?, I.e., is $X_{2015,A}\approx L_A/N_A$, where $N_A$ is the total population of country $A$? I'm asking because if $N_A$ and $N_B$ differ strongly, that can have a major impact - consider what happens if $A$ is the USA and $B$ is Luxembourg.

Comment: By "level", I mean the number of persons employed. I do not divide by the total population.